# Server local connection provider has stopped listening on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ]

Tags: sql-server

Anyone know what specifically causes this error message and/or how to fix it? Thanks.

> SQL Server Alert System: 'Sev 17 Error'
>
> DESCRIPTION:  Server local connection provider has stopped listening on
>   [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ] due to a failure. Error: 0xe8,
>   state: 4. The server will automatically attempt to re-establish
>   listening.